# Get the most recent "Monday 05:30" Unix time in Go?

Tags: go, time

Is there a Time library function or another good way to get the most recent weekday, hour, minute combination in Unix time? For example, given:

day: Monday

hour: 11

minute: 30

And it's currently Tuesday, I want the Unix time for yesterday at 11:30am. Some languages / libraries have support for thing but I cannot find something in Go that would make this easy. Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the definition of `Weekday`, you'll see that Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, etc. So to get to the last Monday, you have to do go back today-Monday, and move back to 11:30 that day. However, this doesn't work if it is already Monday and before 11:30, so you need to check for that:

```
now:=time.Now()
dayOffset:=now.Weekday()-time.Monday
targetDate:=now.AddDate(0,0,-int(dayOffset))
targetDate=time.Date(targetDate.Year(),targetDate.Month(),targetDate.Day(),11,30,0,0,targetDate.Location())
if targetDate.After(now) {
   targetDate=targetDate.AddDate(0,0,-7)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

My attempt at a simple and intuitive solution. See code comments for explanation

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // The target day / hour / minute
    const (
        day = time.Monday
        hour = 21
        minute = 0
    )

    // The starting time to work from
    startTime := time.Now()

    // Create the time on that day with the desired hour and minute
    t := time.Date(startTime.Year(), startTime.Month(), startTime.Day(), hour, minute, 0, 0, startTime.Location())

    // As long as we're on the wrong weekday, or not before the start time, back up one day
    for t.Weekday() != day || !t.Before(startTime){
        t = t.AddDate(0, 0, -1)
    }

    // Print the time, and it's Unix timestamp.
    fmt.Println(t, t.Unix())
}
```